# Send data from server back to the client

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, tcpclient

I have a TcpClient application that send a message from client to the server.
Code below:

clsServer.cs

```
public void server_start()
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(new Byte[] { 172, 16, 1, 55 }), 9999);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));

        _rtb_Input.AppendText("Listening... Press any key to stop" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;
    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);

            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string msg = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
            if (this.MessageReceived != null)
            {
                this.MessageReceived(msg);
            }
            //send message back select the message from the db
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Client!");

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```

frmClient.cs

```
public frmClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void btn_ClientStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.1.55"), 9999);
        try
        {
            client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(rtb_Outpot.Text);

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rtb_Outpot.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine + "Failed To Connect to the Server" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

frmServer.cs

```
private void btn_ServerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_ServerStop.Enabled = true;
        btn_ServerStart.Enabled = false;
        server = new clsServer(rtb_Input);
        server.MessageReceived += new MessageReceivedHandler(Message_Received);
        server.server_start();
    }

    private void Message_Received(string message)
    {
        //update the display using invoke
        Invoke(new MessageReceivedHandler(PrintToScreen), new object[] { message });
    }

    private void PrintToScreen(string msg)
    {
        msg_counter++;
        rtb_Input.AppendText("msg no': " + msg_counter + System.Environment.NewLine + msg + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Works fine, when I send a message from client to the server.
But now I can figure out a way to send data from server back to the client.
Will I have to make a thread for the client form too?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you read after clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); in frmClient?

Comment: Actually, I need a way to RECEIVE the data sent from server to the client. I'am not using the clientStream.Write() yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: @LukinhaRS - Receiving data on the client is no different than receiving it on the server. You're actually using the same type in both situations (typically).

Comment: I use this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974404/socket-programming-multiple-client-one-server works very well to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted looks more like you're trying to find a way to *receive* the message sent from the server. The code in clsServer.cs already contains the code necessary to send data *to* the client.

Your client code is just missing the necessary calls to read the response from `clientStream`. How that is implemented in your application will vary depending on your requirements. Personally, I'd probably offload the reading to another thread.