# Socket Programming multiple client one server

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I am just starting out Socket Programming in C# and am now a bit stuck with this problem. 
How do you handle multiple clients on a single server without creating a thread for each client?

The one thread for each client works fine when there are say 10 clients but if the client number goes up to a 1000 clients is creating a thread for every single one of them advisable? If there is any other method to do this can someone please tel me?

Comment: Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod ... there are a million articles around there if you search for `async socket c#`...

Comment: There are hundreds of examples if you google "introduction to socket programming c#". Also loads of great you-tube videos on the topic if you prefer that.

Comment: Use ipAddress = 0.0.0.0 to listen in all network adapters.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try to use asynchronous server.
The following example program creates a server that receives connection requests from clients. The server is built with an asynchronous socket, so execution of the server application is not suspended while it waits for a connection from a client. The application receives a string from the client, displays the string on the console, and then echoes the string back to the client. The string from the client must contain the string `<EOF>` to signal the end of the message.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject {
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener {
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener() {
    }

    public static void StartListening() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept( 
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener );

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content );
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);
            } else {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.

        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }   

    public static int Main(String[] args) {
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That's will be the best solution.

Comment: I am using this solution in this question, but for some reason the callback doesn't happen immediately but only around 20 seconds later. Can you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418613/socket-buffers-the-data-it-receives

Comment: This solution is incomplete as it assumes you have only one network adapter. If you have two or more network adapters and you want to listen to all of them this solution fails.

Comment: allDone is not visible in the callback. cause the your callback uses a static modifier.

Comment: original article is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: In my case:  Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

Answer (score 1):

Threads can work fine but rarely scales well to that many clients. There are two easy ways and lots of more complex ways to handle that, here's some pseudocode for how the easier two are usually structured to give you an overview.

**select()**

This is a call to check which sockets have new clients or data waiting on them, a typical program looks something like this.

```
server = socket(), bind(), listen()
while(run)
   status = select(server)
   if has new client
       newclient = server.accept()
       handle add client
   if has new data
       read and handle data
```

Which means no threads are needed to handle multiple clients, but it doesn't really scale well either if handle data take a long time, then you won't read new data or accept new clients until that's done.

**Async sockets**

This is another way of handling sockets which is kind of abstracted above select. You just set up callbacks for common events and let the framework do the not-so-heavy lifting.

```
 function handleNewClient() { do stuff and then beginReceive(handleNewData) }
 function handleNewData() { do stuff and then beginReceive(handleNewData) }
 server = create, bind, listen etc
 server.beginAddNewClientHandler(handleNewClient)
 server.start()
```

I think this should scale better if your data handling take a long time. What kind of data handling will you be doing?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044852/20-receives-per-second-with-socketasynceventargs) could be a good starting point. If you want to avoid 1 thread <-> 1 client; then you should use async socket facilities provided in .NET. Core object to use here is [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx).